# In linux, how to create an "intercepted/redirected" symbolic link?

Tags: linux, bash

How can one,in Linux, create something like a symbolic link (hereby referred to as A) so that any program reading from a will read from an original file (B), but writing to A will instead write to a different file (C), in a way that writing to A will leave B unaffected?

Comment: After C is created, shall reading anew still read B?

Comment: Please make sure there is no [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) here. [Edit] the question if there is.

Comment: I very much doubt you could do this without a (virtual) file system (like _overlayfs_).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski yes

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: If you don't want the file to change simply don't write to it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do this.

It may be possible with an overlayfs, but setting this up is complicated and for a single file even more so.

It is also possible to write a kernel module that intercepts the necessary system calls to implement such a feature. As far as I know, no-one has done this yet.

You should reconsider your use-case.